# Need only single table from ibdata1 file

Tags: innodb, recovery, ibdata

I currently have a corrupt database on my live site, because a single Table that has gone missing.

`Table 'test1.catalog_product_index_price' doesn't exist`

I logged onto my server and downloaded a compressed backup file "/backup/2018-02-03/system/dirs/_var_lib_mysql_.tar.gz"

Once i extracted it locally I noticed ibdata1 file, and this would be my first time trying to work with this type of file.

I only need to recover a single table from the "test1" database. How can I go about exporting this table using the ibdata1 file?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would put the whole backup file onto a testserver, is that possible for you? And then do: 
mysqldump -u root -p test1 catalog_product_index_price > dump_catalog_product_index_price.sql

Comment: Yes this worked, thanks. I created a test server locally with MAMP and copied all the files over to /Applications/MAMP/db/mysql/. Finally restored my table and restarted MySQL

Comment: Sweet! Glad i could help. How about an upvote then? ;-)